# How can I get my specific location (latitude and longitude) in a c# windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to find my specific location or latitude and longitude in a c# windows form.
But the problem is that the latitude and longitude that are given to me are not correct.

So can I get the latitude and longitude?

```
var res = "";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ipinfo.io" + ip);
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            res += line;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: _"But the problem the latitude and longitude that given to me is not correct"_. With no code, I'm surprised you're getting any latitude and longitude at all!

Comment: What do you mean with not correct? you are near to you or you are in a completely different place? Latitude and Logitude under windows are not so accurate.

Comment: OP, please edit your question to include the faulty code and a description of how the result you get is incorrect.

Comment: using ip address i get latitude and longitude of my location but is wrong

Comment: Yeah, GeoIP isn't exact. It's was even worse when I was on ADSL. I'd see a location a 6 hour drive away. You should be thankful for that really, otherwise anyone with your IP address would know exactly where you live.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher= new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
watcher.Start(); //started watcher
GeoCoordinate coord = watcher.Position.Location;
if (!watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown)
{
    double lat = coord.Latitude; //latitude
    double long = coord.Longitude;  //logitude
}
```